# Edit all rows at once + import encoding issues

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, notepad++

```
"LJUBLJANA DOBRUNJE";"LJUBLJANA";1261,00;;"Ljubljanska"
"LJUBLJANA DRAVLJE";"LJUBLJANA DRAVLJE";1117,00;"LJUBLJANA";"Ljubljanska"
"LJUBLJANA MOSTE 1000";"LJUBLJANA";1000,00;"LJUBLJANA";"Ljubljanska"
"LJUBLJANA P.P.";"LJUBLJANA";1001,00;"LJUBLJANA";"Ljubljanska"
"LJUBLJANA POLJE";"LJUBLJANA POLJE";1260,00;"LJUBLJANA";"Ljubljanska"
"LJUBLJANA ŠENTVID";"LJUBLJANA ŠENTVID";1210,00;"LJUBLJANA";"Ljubljanska"
"LJUBLJANA ŠMARTNO";"LJUBLJANA ŠMARTNO";1211,00;"LJUBLJANA";"Ljubljanska"
"LJUBLJANA VIČ 1111";"LJUBLJANA";1111,00;"LJUBLJANA";"Ljubljanska"
```

I want to get rid of those zeroes (,00) next to the postal codes. (Using notepad ++ if possible).

Also, when importing this .csv file with phpmyadmin, all characters (č,ž,š) dissapear. I use correct (UTF-8) encoding setting (phpmyadmin).

Thank you :)

Comment: In Notepad++ just use Find & Replace (CTRL+H) and search for ,00 and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the encoding part.
I opened the .csv file in notepad and saved it as UTF-8.
It works like a charm now when importing with phpmyadmin.

P.S. Just make sure your database is utf-8 too :))